# How to efficiently fetch multiple ST_Value from PostGIS raster(s)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-raster, postgis-3.0

I have a raster table with index created by `raster2pgsql`

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl (rid serial PRIMARY KEY, rast raster);
CREATE INDEX ON tbl USING gist (st_convexhull(rast));
```

I can see the best way to fetch a single point value is

```sql
SELECT ST_Value(rast, :point) FROM tbl WHERE ST_ConvexHull(rast) ~ :point;
```

However, given the structure and the functions I can see, it's not obvious how to best fetch e.g. 1000 point values at once. Neither from a single tile, not if they span across tiles.

I had an initial try with `MULTIPOINT` geometry, but they don't work with `ST_Value`, and I didn't know where to start with the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To account for repeated points, boundaries, and overlapping or missing rasters, this was my final solution:

```
SELECT (array_agg(ST_Value(r.rast, pt.geom) ORDER BY r.rid DESC)
        FILTER ( WHERE ST_Value(r.rast, pt.geom) IS NOT NULL ))[1] 
FROM tbl AS r 
  RIGHT JOIN ST_Dump(:multipoint) AS pt 
  ON ST_ConvexHull(r.rast) ~ pt.geom
GROUP BY pt.path;
```

Answer (score 3):

This should trivially be

```
SELECT ST_Value(r.rast, pt.geom)
FROM   <raster> AS r
JOIN   <points> AS pt
  ON   ST_Intersects(r.rast, pt.geom)
;
```

where `<points>` can be **any table expression** you can think of.

Comment: This decides to use a Seq Scan instead of the index in various cases, which destroys the performance. For example, if `<points>` is `st_dump`. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't use the index for multiple points at all, so this is pretty bad.

Comment: `ST_Dump` results themselves are *never* covered by an index, nor any other *derived* geometries (unless covered by a *functional* index). `ST_Intersects` is supposed to use the index on `rast` only, and the planner may deem a `Seq scan` to be more efficient in cases when it expects to have to scan more than a percentage of the table. Update statistics *may* help: `VACUUM ANALYZE <raster_table>;`.

Comment: o fix this it should be `ST_Intersects(ST_ConvexHull(r.rast), pt.geom)`. Then it uses the index regardless of the structure and cardinality of `<points>`

Comment: You're welcome to update my answer! I cannot check the structure of a PostGIS raster table right now; is there a *functional* index on `ST_ConvexHull` on the raster table? If not, the only index usable is that of `<points>`, which can never be the result of a geometry dump, or any dynamic or derived geometry (except another *functional* index for the latter).

Comment: The index it creates is `CREATE INDEX ON tbl USING gist (ST_ConvexHull(rast));`. Possibly I should have clarified that in the question.

Comment: It also turns out that using the operator directly (`~` or `&&`) is significantly faster than the function (`ST_Contains` or `ST_Intersects``)